# Uniform Spaces: Extension

Tags: general-topology

Given uniform spaces $(X,\mathcal{U})$ and $(X_0,\mathcal{U}_0)$.
And a complete Hausdorff uniform space $(Y,\mathcal{V})$.

Suppose initial uniformity:
$$\tau:X_0\to X:\quad\mathcal{B}_0=\tau_0^{-1}\mathcal{U}$$

Consider a uniform function:
$$F_0:X_0\to Z:\quad F_0^{-1}\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{U}_0$$

Extend it uniformly:
$$F\left(x\in\overline{\tau_0X_0}\right):=\lim_{\tau_0x_0\to x}F_0(x_0)\\
F\left(x\notin\overline{\tau_0X_0}\right):=y_\infty\in Y$$

Then it remains uniform:
$$F:X\to Y:\quad F^{-1}\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$$
But how can I prove this?

Comment: The closed entourages form a basis of the uniformity $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do you mean Bourbaki, Topology of a Uniform Space, Corollary 2??

Comment: Perhaps. I don't have that available to see if it's that. Probably it is. I mean that that fact is useful in the proof.